# Generating a dynamic data table grid for the OpenAI API response

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

I'm currently developing a chatbot for an iOS app, leveraging the OpenAI API. One of the challenges I'm facing is dynamically creating a table grid. My aim is to display each NSAttributedString within a dynamically generated grid, mirroring the structure depicted here:

[image]

what i am getting right now from my chatbot response which is openai api is the line breaks like this "---|---|---|---|--- |

"  which is not professional:

[image]

The codes for table grid need to appear inside the:

```
    mutating internal func visitTable(_ table: Table) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()

        return result
    }
```

These are my current codes, where I'm using Markdownosaur to highlight the functioning portions. My question is centered around the lines that separate the rows and columns. I'm seeking refinements to achieve a professional-looking table grid, akin to the one depicted in the first image. How can I enhance the presentation of the table lines for a more polished appearance?

```
//
//  MarkdownAttributedStringParser.swift
//  Besa
//
//  Created by Artit on 12/01/24.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import Markdown
import Highlighter

/// Based on the source code from Christian Selig
/// https://github.com/christianselig/Markdownosaur/blob/main/Sources/Markdownosaur/Markdownosaur.swift

public struct MarkdownAttributedStringParser: MarkupVisitor {
    let baseFontSize: CGFloat = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).pointSize
    let highlighter: Highlighter = {
        let highlighter = Highlighter()!
        highlighter.setTheme("stackoverflow-dark")
        return highlighter
    }()
    
    let newLineFontSize: CGFloat = 12

    public init() {}
    
    public mutating func attributedString(from document: Document) -> NSAttributedString {
        return visit(document)
    }
    
    mutating func parserResults(from document: Document) -> [ParserResult] {
        var results = [ParserResult]()
        var currentAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        func appendCurrentAttrString(tableData: [[NSAttributedString]]) {
            if !currentAttrString.string.isEmpty {
                let currentAttrStringToAppend = (try? AttributedString(currentAttrString, including: \.uiKit)) ?? AttributedString(stringLiteral: currentAttrString.string)
                results.append(.init(attributedString: currentAttrStringToAppend, isCodeBlock: false, codeBlockLanguage: nil))
            }
        }

        document.children.forEach { markup in
            let attrString = visit(markup)
            if let codeBlock = markup as? CodeBlock {
                appendCurrentAttrString(tableData: [])
                let attrStringToAppend = (try? AttributedString(attrString, including: \.uiKit)) ?? AttributedString(stringLiteral: attrString.string)
                results.append(.init(attributedString: attrStringToAppend, isCodeBlock: true, codeBlockLanguage: codeBlock.language))
                currentAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
            } else {
                currentAttrString.append(attrString)
            }
        }

        appendCurrentAttrString(tableData: [])
        return results
    }
    
    mutating public func defaultVisit(_ markup: Markup) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        for child in markup.children {
            result.append(visit(child))
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    mutating public func visitText(_ text: Text) -> NSAttributedString {
        return NSAttributedString(string: text.plainText, attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: baseFontSize, weight: .regular)])
    }
    
    mutating public func visitEmphasis(_ emphasis: Emphasis) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        for child in emphasis.children {
            result.append(visit(child))
        }
        
        result.applyEmphasis()
        
        return result
    }
    
    
    mutating internal func visitTable(_ table: Table) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()

        return result
    }




    
    
    mutating public func visitStrong(_ strong: Strong) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        for child in strong.children {
            result.append(visit(child))
        }
        
        result.applyStrong()
        
        return result
    }
    
    mutating public func visitParagraph(_ paragraph: Paragraph) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        for child in paragraph.children {
            result.append(visit(child))
        }
        
        if paragraph.hasSuccessor {
            result.append(paragraph.isContainedInList ? .singleNewline(withFontSize: newLineFontSize) : .doubleNewline(withFontSize: newLineFontSize))
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    mutating public func visitHeading(_ heading: Heading) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        for child in heading.children {
            result.append(visit(child))
        }
        
        result.applyHeading(withLevel: heading.level)
        
        if heading.hasSuccessor {
            result.append(.doubleNewline(withFontSize: newLineFontSize))
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    mutating public func visitLink(_ link: Link) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        for child in link.children {
            result.append(visit(child))
        }
        
        let url = link.destination != nil ? URL(string: link.destination!) : nil
        
        result.applyLink(withURL: url)
        
        return result
    }
    
    mutating public func visitInlineCode(_ inlineCode: InlineCode) -> NSAttributedString {
        return NSAttributedString(string: inlineCode.code, attributes: [.font: UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: baseFontSize - 1.0, weight: .regular), .foregroundColor: UIColor.systemPink])
    }
    
    public func visitCodeBlock(_ codeBlock: CodeBlock) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: highlighter.highlight(codeBlock.code, as: codeBlock.language) ?? NSAttributedString(string: codeBlock.code))
        
        if codeBlock.hasSuccessor {
            result.append(.singleNewline(withFontSize: newLineFontSize))
        }
    
        return result
    }
    
    mutating public func visitStrikethrough(_ strikethrough: Strikethrough) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        for child in strikethrough.children {
            result.append(visit(child))
        }
        
        result.applyStrikethrough()
        
        return result
    }
    
    mutating public func visitUnorderedList(_ unorderedList: UnorderedList) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: baseFontSize, weight: .regular)
                
        for listItem in unorderedList.listItems {
            var listItemAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [:]
            
            let listItemParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            
            let baseLeftMargin: CGFloat = 15.0
            let leftMarginOffset = baseLeftMargin + (20.0 * CGFloat(unorderedList.listDepth))
            let spacingFromIndex: CGFloat = 8.0
            let bulletWidth = ceil(NSAttributedString(string: "•", attributes: [.font: font]).size().width)
            let firstTabLocation = leftMarginOffset + bulletWidth
            let secondTabLocation = firstTabLocation + spacingFromIndex
            
            listItemParagraphStyle.tabStops = [
                NSTextTab(textAlignment: .right, location: firstTabLocation),
                NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: secondTabLocation)
            ]
            
            listItemParagraphStyle.headIndent = secondTabLocation
            
            listItemAttributes[.paragraphStyle] = listItemParagraphStyle
            listItemAttributes[.font] = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: baseFontSize, weight: .regular)
            listItemAttributes[.listDepth] = unorderedList.listDepth
            
            let listItemAttributedString = visit(listItem).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
            listItemAttributedString.insert(NSAttributedString(string: "\t•\t", attributes: listItemAttributes), at: 0)
            
            result.append(listItemAttributedString)
        }
        
        if unorderedList.hasSuccessor {
            result.append(.doubleNewline(withFontSize: newLineFontSize))
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    mutating public func visitListItem(_ listItem: ListItem) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        for child in listItem.children {
            result.append(visit(child))
        }
        
        if listItem.hasSuccessor {
            result.append(.singleNewline(withFontSize: newLineFontSize))
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    mutating public func visitOrderedList(_ orderedList: OrderedList) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        for (index, listItem) in orderedList.listItems.enumerated() {
            var listItemAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [:]
            
            let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: baseFontSize, weight: .regular)
            let numeralFont = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: baseFontSize, weight: .regular)
            
            let listItemParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            
            // Implement a base amount to be spaced from the left side at all times to better visually differentiate it as a list
            let baseLeftMargin: CGFloat = 15.0
            let leftMarginOffset = baseLeftMargin + (20.0 * CGFloat(orderedList.listDepth))
            
            // Grab the highest number to be displayed and measure its width (yes normally some digits are wider than others but since we're using the numeral mono font all will be the same width in this case)
            let highestNumberInList = orderedList.childCount
            let numeralColumnWidth = ceil(NSAttributedString(string: "\(highestNumberInList).", attributes: [.font: numeralFont]).size().width)
            
            let spacingFromIndex: CGFloat = 8.0
            let firstTabLocation = leftMarginOffset + numeralColumnWidth
            let secondTabLocation = firstTabLocation + spacingFromIndex
            
            listItemParagraphStyle.tabStops = [
                NSTextTab(textAlignment: .right, location: firstTabLocation),
                NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: secondTabLocation)
            ]
            
            listItemParagraphStyle.headIndent = secondTabLocation
            
            listItemAttributes[.paragraphStyle] = listItemParagraphStyle
            listItemAttributes[.font] = font
            listItemAttributes[.listDepth] = orderedList.listDepth

            let listItemAttributedString = visit(listItem).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
            
            // Same as the normal list attributes, but for prettiness in formatting we want to use the cool monospaced numeral font
            var numberAttributes = listItemAttributes
            numberAttributes[.font] = numeralFont
            
            let numberAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\t\(index + 1).\t", attributes: numberAttributes)
            listItemAttributedString.insert(numberAttributedString, at: 0)
            
            result.append(listItemAttributedString)
        }
        
        if orderedList.hasSuccessor {
            result.append(orderedList.isContainedInList ? .singleNewline(withFontSize: newLineFontSize) : .doubleNewline(withFontSize: newLineFontSize))
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    mutating public func visitBlockQuote(_ blockQuote: BlockQuote) -> NSAttributedString {
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        for child in blockQuote.children {
            var quoteAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [:]
            
            let quoteParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            
            let baseLeftMargin: CGFloat = 15.0
            let leftMarginOffset = baseLeftMargin + (20.0 * CGFloat(blockQuote.quoteDepth))
            
            quoteParagraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: leftMarginOffset)]
            
            quoteParagraphStyle.headIndent = leftMarginOffset
            
            quoteAttributes[.paragraphStyle] = quoteParagraphStyle
            quoteAttributes[.font] = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: baseFontSize, weight: .regular)
            quoteAttributes[.listDepth] = blockQuote.quoteDepth
            
            let quoteAttributedString = visit(child).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
            quoteAttributedString.insert(NSAttributedString(string: "\t", attributes: quoteAttributes), at: 0)
            
            quoteAttributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.systemGray)
            
            result.append(quoteAttributedString)
        }
        
        if blockQuote.hasSuccessor {
            result.append(.doubleNewline(withFontSize: newLineFontSize))
        }
        
        return result
    }
}

// MARK: - Extensions Land




extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func applyEmphasis() {
        enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: length), options: []) { value, range, stop in
            guard let font = value as? UIFont else { return }
            
            let newFont = font.apply(newTraits: .traitItalic)
            addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
        }
    }
    
    func applyStrong() {
        enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: length), options: []) { value, range, stop in
            guard let font = value as? UIFont else { return }
            
            let newFont = font.apply(newTraits: .traitBold)
            addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
        }
    }
    
    func applyLink(withURL url: URL?) {
        addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.systemBlue)
        
        if let url = url {
            addAttribute(.link, value: url)
        }
    }
    
    func applyBlockquote() {
        addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.systemGray)
    }
    
    func applyHeading(withLevel headingLevel: Int) {
        enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: length), options: []) { value, range, stop in
            guard let font = value as? UIFont else { return }
            
            let newFont = font.apply(newTraits: .traitBold, newPointSize: 28.0 - CGFloat(headingLevel * 2))
            addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
        }
    }
    
    func applyStrikethrough() {
        addAttribute(.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue)
    }
    
    
    
    
}




extension UIFont {
    func apply(newTraits: UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits, newPointSize: CGFloat? = nil) -> UIFont {
        var existingTraits = fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
        existingTraits.insert(newTraits)
        
        guard let newFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(existingTraits) else { return self }
        return UIFont(descriptor: newFontDescriptor, size: newPointSize ?? pointSize)
    }
}

extension ListItemContainer {
    /// Depth of the list if nested within others. Index starts at 0.
    var listDepth: Int {
        var index = 0

        var currentElement = parent

        while currentElement != nil {
            if currentElement is ListItemContainer {
                index += 1
            }

            currentElement = currentElement?.parent
        }
        
        return index
    }
}

extension BlockQuote {
    /// Depth of the quote if nested within others. Index starts at 0.
    var quoteDepth: Int {
        var index = 0

        var currentElement = parent

        while currentElement != nil {
            if currentElement is BlockQuote {
                index += 1
            }

            currentElement = currentElement?.parent
        }
        
        return index
    }
}

extension NSAttributedString.Key {
    static let listDepth = NSAttributedString.Key("ListDepth")
    static let quoteDepth = NSAttributedString.Key("QuoteDepth")
}

extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func addAttribute(_ name: NSAttributedString.Key, value: Any) {
        addAttribute(name, value: value, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))
    }
    
    func addAttributes(_ attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]) {
        addAttributes(attrs, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))
    }
}

extension Markup {
    /// Returns true if this element has sibling elements after it.
    var hasSuccessor: Bool {
        guard let childCount = parent?.childCount else { return false }
        return indexInParent < childCount - 1
    }
    
    var isContainedInList: Bool {
        var currentElement = parent

        while currentElement != nil {
            if currentElement is ListItemContainer {
                return true
            }

            currentElement = currentElement?.parent
        }
        
        return false
    }
}




extension NSAttributedString {
    static func singleNewline(withFontSize fontSize: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
        return NSAttributedString(string: "\n", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)])
    }

    static func doubleNewline(withFontSize fontSize: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
        return NSAttributedString(string: "\n\n", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .regular)])
    }
}
```

Comment: I would really not recommend pulling markdown string data from a generative API.  I think this is a poor design considering you can constraint the output to be more predictable like JSON.

If you can do that part taking a strongly typed JSON file is very straightforward.

But good luck!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the response @EvanAnger but i need the markdown to highlight the codes that are generated from the API.

Comment: @Community The problem is very simple, its about how to design the borders of the grid table to show a beautiful table grid similar as the first pic, the data of the table grid is dynamically based the chatbot API.

Comment: I think the confusion is that you're using some open source library that you think should be able to something because it does markdown.  Furthermore all the code you pasted looks manipulation of NSAttributedString/Formatting.  So you're asking for decorations outside of the string.

This is why I recommended approaching the problem differently so you could use UIKit/SwiftUI directly (would be very easy)

Comment: [Case in point, doesn't looked like its supported with this OSS library](https://github.com/christianselig/Markdownosaur/issues/6)

Comment: @EvanAnger thanks Evan for you time, yes i saw it now that someone has opened an issue about supporting tables and images, do you know how to do it directly the table grid using UIKit/SwiftUI with dynamical table data?

Comment: Do I know how to take Markdown and convert it to a table-based UIKit/SwiftUI, no but might be a newer library out there like [this](https://github.com/gonzalezreal/swift-markdown-ui), which might be able to do it.  If you're controlling the actual API, I'd recommend setting back JSON to the client instead though.

Answer (score -1):

This is an API you're working through so I would recommend relying on a more typical format.

I've done something similar which made this more predicable for the client iOS app to consume.

```
  const result = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [
      {role: "user", content: message},
      {role: "system", content: systemMessage},
    ],
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  });
```

User message is what is being input from chat.
Here's an example systemMessage to coincide with the user message.  **Key point, this ensures the response back to client is in a JSON format.**

```
You will be provided with unstructured data on subject the user wants to learn about. Gather information on the subjects and provide 10 questions with multiple choices in the following json format 

{"subjects": [ {"name":"<Subject Name>","questions": [ {"question":"<Actual Information>","answer":"<Answer Value>","answerOptions": ["<Possible Answers>" ] } ] } ]}
```

(this was a multiple choice trivia generator, but I'm sure you can come up with something that satisfies your scenario.)

After that I'm just serializing the data, and loading that strongly typed data into my view.